# Data Storage options for power apps

Tags: database, azure, powerapps

I'm building an application that will be used in a sales aspect by sales reps for many different clients at the same time. This means that each sales rep will have a device that will run the app and will be importing and running operations using the client's data during the sales demo. This also means that during the demo, we don't want different client's seeing other's data. We would like to have the data exist only on that 'instance' of the power app. I'm not very familiar with how Power Apps stores data, but the types of data will most likely be storing temporarily for each demo would be things such as data files or input data. Is there a way to 'instance' the data in this way using Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about powerapps **Canvas App** you have an option to choose from wide array of datasources.

> From Microsoft article
>
> The most common data sources are tables, which you can use to retrieve
> and store information. You can use connections to data sources to read
> and write data in Microsoft Excel workbooks, lists created using
> Microsoft Lists, SharePoint libraries, SQL tables, and many other
> formats, which can be stored in cloud services such as OneDrive for
> Business, DropBox, and SQL Server.

Example, You can architect your app to pull data from excel/csv from one drive based on client name. On the beginning of the app you can have a screen to choose the client and based on selection the data source can be switched to respective folder and load data. Many other possibile solutions are there depends on the requirement.

**Reference**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-data-sources